# Will there still be space for HDD after installing 64GB SSD into laptop?

Tags: ssd, lenovo-laptop

I'm considering considering the base model of [Lenovo Y580](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/builder.workflow:Enter?sb=:000001C9:0000393D:), and install an 64gb ssd that I already have:
http://www3.pny.com/64GB-OPTIMA-SSD-25-SATA-III-MLC-SSD-P2743C394.aspx
There should be nothing wrong with this setup correct?

64GB is only big enough for my OS, but will there be any space for me to keep the HDD inside as well? Or do I have to get an external HDD, instead?

Comment: Why would you get a laptop with the second fastest mobile gaming graphics card available, and terrible screen resolution?  Are you going to always use it with an external monitor?

Comment: should be a 1920x1080 with that graphics card at 15.6", or it is a waste of graphics power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laptops with two hard disk slots do exist, but are quite rare, and mostly only 17" and larger.

Often you can get a hard disk carrier that replaces your optical disk drive.

And, as you noted, using an external disk drive for additional capacity is also an option.  Look for either eSATA or USB3 support, other options will be painfully slow.

Comment: nice, didn't know a caddy was an option. I think I'll just get that, pretty cheap and I can use the default HDD.

Answer (score 0):

The SSD is the same form factor as a regular hard drive, and will replace it. Unless it's a really weird laptop (with multiple hard drive bays), you won't get to have two drives, and will need an external drive if you want to store more than 64 GB.